# Do I need to manually compress AJAX POST from the browser in JS when working over HTTPS, or is it done automatically?

Tags: ajax, ssl, post, https, gzip

For example, every minute I send JSON (20 Kb) to the server, which writes to the database. If I manually compress this data in JS via LZW and send it as binary data, then their size will be only 5 KB.

I find some old articles that briefly say that when connecting via SSL, you don’t need to compress anything, since this is done at the protocol level. However, I did not find anything detailed.

Can you please tell me if this is true and where can I find out more? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Most SSL implementations disable compression at the SSL level for security reasons. Compression at the HTTP level is common and negotiated via HTTP headers. however. Both of those implement transparent network-only compression. When you get the data back from those protocols it's always uncompressed. If you want to store the data compressed then you have to compress it yourself.